# i want to import image from my local storage using next js

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

recently i am learning next.js.

i have some question about import image from my local storage.

this is the err

./logo/Iu.jpg
TypeError: unsupported file type: undefined (file: undefined)

and here is my code

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Iu from "../../logo/Iu.jpg";

const Banner = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image src={Iu} layout="fill" objectFit="contain" objectPosition="left" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Banner;
```

absolutely, installed next-images and, next.config.js has done, so i can import svg file, but could not import png, jpg file

just in case, i also have installed file-loader and wrote webpack.config.js,

please help me..

Comment: Where in your code are you using local storage? Or is the question simply about loading an image file for the local file system?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

keep file in `/public/logo/Iu.jpg`

import using the path `"/logo/Iu.jpg"`

Comment: Trying.. but, Module not found: Can't resolve '/logo/Iu.jpg'  ㅠ_ㅠ ,

Comment: @suwan You don't import the file from the path, you use it directly as the `src` of the image, i.e. `<Image src="/logo/Iu.jpg" layout="fill" objectFit="contain" objectPosition="left" />`.

Comment: oh!! thank you ., now, i understood.., i love you so much,